# JQuery Validation For Duplicate Record In DB

Tags: jquery

How Can we use Jquery Validtion for Duplicate Record in MySql Database?

this is my first jsp file.

```
function dept_check(){           
   var username = $('#C_name').val();
   if(username == "" || username.length < 4){        
      $('#C_name').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
     //$('#tick').hide();
  }
  else{      
   jQuery.ajax({        
      type: "POST",    
      data: 'name='+ username,
      url: "ValidationDepartment.jsp",
      cache: false,                         
      success: function(response){          
         if(response == 1) {
           alert("if")
         //Block of Code 
         }
         else {
            //Block Of Code 
         }
     }
  });
}
```

this is my database file.

```
    Connection conn = DBDepartment.getConnection();
    int check = 0;
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String s1 = session.getAttribute("name").toString();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery("select Dept_name from department");
     while (resultSet.next()) {
         if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("Dept_name"))){
             check++;
             conn.close();
         }
     }
```

now how can we check that data is already exist in database?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("Dept_name"))){
         check++;
         out.print( check ) ;
         conn.close();
         break;
     }
```